# Insert multiple data as well as update in database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I get Nearest 50 km location names from current location using google api, so it' works fine.

So I need to insert all these locations into my database. If some location already there in database, I need to update these location.

For example I get 10 locations in google api so 5 locations are already there in my database. I need to 5 location are update and remaining 5 locations are insert.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';
$LocaName=$_REQUEST['locname'];
$address=$_REQUEST['address'];
$latt=$_REQUEST['Latt'];
$long=$_REQUEST['Long'];

if($latt && $long)
{
    $LocaNamearray = explode("|||", $LocaName);
    $addressarray = explode("|||", $address);
    $lattarray=explode("|||",$latt);
    $longarray=explode("|||",$long);

    for($i=0;$i<count($lattarray);$i++)
    {
        $query1="select * from tbl_MapDetails where Latitude='".$lattarray[$i]."'and Longitude='".$longarray[$i]."'";
        $result1=mysql_query($query1);
        $now=mysql_num_rows($result1);
    }

    if($now >=1)
    {
        for($k=0;$k<count($lattarray);$k++)
        {
            $query="update tbl_MapDetails set LocationName='".$LocaNamearray[$k]."', Address='".$addressarray[$k]."',Latitude='".$lattarray[$k]."', Longitude='".$longarray[$k]."' where Latitude='".$lattarray[$k]."'and Longitude='".$longarray[$k]."'";
        }
        $nav="update";
    }
    else 
    {

        $query ="INSERT INTO tbl_MapDetails(LocationName,Address,Latitude,Longitude) VALUES";
        $strDelimiter = "";

        for($j=0;$j<count($LocaNamearray);$j++)
        {
            $name =$LocaNamearray[$j];
            $address =$addressarray[$j];
            $lat = $lattarray[$j];
            $long = $longarray[$j];
            $query .= $strDelimiter."('$name', '$address','$lat','$long')";
            $strDelimiter = ',';
        }
        $nav="Add";
    }

    $result= mysql_query($query);

    if($result)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
        $message=array("message"=>"sucessfully".$nav);
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
        $message=array("message"=>"fail".$nav);
    }
}
else
{
    $message=array("message"=>"require latt and long");
}

echo json_encode($message);

?>
```

Here insert and update working but I need to check every location in database. There is no location in database. It need to insert other location are update. how to check both these conditions matched locations are update and unmatched locations are inserted  Please guide me.

Comment: Hi user816891, Your code is quite hard to read. You will find people are more likely to help you if you format your code well. Also, you should try and give more details about your problem. What is/isn't happening? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error message.

Comment: thanks for your response..in this code i am not getting any error ok lets explain example i get 10 location so first i have to check  if location are already there or not if already there update  these location based on lattitude and logituide there no locations add these location into database so my problem is some locations are already there in database some locations are not there so i need execute both update and insert also so i want to know how check these conditions...plz guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong in the code. What you are doing is looping through the provided data and for each set of data checking if a location with that lat/long exists and storing it in the $now variable. Once you've finished that loop, you're then checking $now and looping through the provided data again and either INSERTing or UPDATEing each set of data. So if the last set of data exists, your script will try and UPDATE each set of data. If it doesn't, your script will try to INSERT each set of data. Your code should be something like this (mixture of your code and pseudo-code):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($lattarray);$i++)
{
    $query1="select * from tbl_MapDetails where Latitude='".$lattarray[$i]."'and Longitude='".$longarray[$i]."'";
    $result1=mysql_query($query1);
    $now=mysql_num_rows($result1);


    if($now >=1)
    {
        // update table with location details
    } 
    else
    {
        // insert location details into table
    }
}
```

If this becomes a performance issue you could look at retrieving all the SELECT data first but if you're only dealing with 10 rows at a time you should be OK.

Note: depending on where your $_REQUEST data is coming from you might want to do some validation, i.e. to check you have matching sets of lat/long/name/address details.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at MySQL`s [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). But you must be careful, because it is quite slow operation.
But, I think, it would be better if you just union all your SELECT requests in one using OR conditions.